# Wrong usage of AES library?

Tags: c, aes

I want to use a memory-saving AES-128 implementation. I found the implementation of [Karl Malbrain](http://www.geocities.ws/malbrain/aestable_c.html).

I am using it with the code below:

```
void encryptUboot(void){
    //uint8_t  key[AES_KEY_LENGTH] = {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99};
    uint8_t  key[AES_KEY_LENGTH] = {0x54, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x61, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x21, 0x21};
    uint8_t  keyschedule[AES_KEY_LENGTH * AES_ROUNDS] = {0x00};
    uint8_t message[5] = "test";
    uint8_t cipher[16] = {0x00};
    uint8_t i;

    if(debug)   printf("\n[D] Running AES-128 encryption\n");

    aes_expand_key(key, keyschedule);
    aes_encrypt(message, keyschedule, cipher);
    printf("message: %s | cipher: ", message);
    for(i = 0; i<AES_KEY_LENGTH; i++){
        printf("%02x ", cipher[i]);
    }

}
```

This outputs:

`[D] Running AES-128 encryption

message: test | cipher: 2d 58 45 71 24 43 f5 cd 69 6d 07 b3 a3 29 de 8f`

However, using the code from [here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=2875) (zip file) with the code below ...

```
// AES usage example
// compile as: gcc main.c aes.h aes.c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "aes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned char key[KEY_128] = {0x54, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x61, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x21, 0x21};
    unsigned char ptext[16] = "test";
    unsigned char ctext[16];
    unsigned char decptext[16];
    unsigned int i = 0;
    aes_ctx_t *ctx;

    init_aes();
    ctx = aes_alloc_ctx(key, sizeof(key));
    if(!ctx) {
            perror("aes_alloc_ctx");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    aes_encrypt(ctx, ptext, ctext);
    for(i=0;i<KEY_128;i++)  printf("%02x ", ctext[i]);
    puts("");
    aes_decrypt(ctx, ctext, decptext);
    puts(decptext);

    aes_free_ctx(ctx);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

.. it outputs a different cipher:

`1f 53 3f 60 15 d5 ab 16 69 b6 c6 3b 9e 77 2f 0c

test`

Do you see my mistake? Obviously, I am instrumenting these libraries in a wrong way.

Thanks,
-P

Comment: you should look at the key schedule : how is it build for the second example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I couldn't find the exact function you use in Malbrains code, I believe your problem lies in the difference in array length for `message`. The algorithm encrypts blocks of 128 bit (16 bytes), but you only allocated 5 bytes.

```
uint8_t message[5] = "test";
```

vs

```
unsigned char ptext[16] = "test";
```

Try initialising it with exactly the same data.

```
uint8_t message[16];
memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
memcpy(message, "test", 5);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly the reason. Now everything works fine!